# electron app crashed when I import a file

Tags: typescript, electron

---

**SOLUTION (although I would still LOVE an explanation)**

if I include the interface code directly (without import) at the TOP of the preload.ts file everything works fine. I can cast to objects like I expected.

---

I have an electron app compiled to typescript. I have a main.ts and a preload.ts as shown in the starter [example here](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript). When I import a files into the preload.ts the app crashes right where the import is used. What am I doing wrong here?

The error says:

> `api` is not defined

which is completely incorrect because the code works perfectly if the `CandleRes` import is removed at the marked lines below.

After some testing I found that:

- The import statement itself doesn't seem to cause problems. When I remove the import and put the interfaces directly in the file I still get the same error
- **When I include the interface by copying and pasting in the preload.ts file (at the bottom) the file crashes** whether or not I make any reference to the interface

**main.ts**

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import * as path from "path";

let mainWindow: Electron.BrowserWindow;

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    },
    width: 800
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "../index.html"));

}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("activate", () => {
  // On OS X it"s common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

**preload.ts**

```
import { CandleRes } from "./models"; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<THIS LINE CAUSES CRASH
let api: any;

// All of the Node.js APIs are available in the preload process.
// It has the same sandbox as a Chrome extension.

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  replaceText("colnames", "Loading data...."); //<<<<<<<<<<THIS FIRES CORRECTLY
  setupApi(); //Omitted to save space. This inits the var api
  await getDataAsync();
});

async function getDataAsync() {
  try {
    let candles: CandleRes = ( //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<I attempt to use import here. App crashes
      await this.api.getCandles("USD_CAD", {
        granularity: "M5",
        count: 1
      })
    ).data;
    replaceText("currencies", candles + " string: " + JSON.stringify(candles));
  } catch (e) {
    replaceText("currencies", "currencies ERR: " + e);
  }
}
const replaceText = (selector: string, text: string) => {
  const element = document.getElementById(selector);
  if (element) {
    element.innerText = selector + ":" + text;
  }
};
function setupApi() {
  var key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //https://www.oanda.com/demo-account/tpa/personal_token
  var acctid = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"; //https://www.oanda.com/demo-account/funding
  const Oanda = require("oanda-node-api");

  const config = {
    env: "fxPractice",
    auth: `Bearer ${key}`,
    accountID: acctid,
    dateFormat: "RFC3339"
  };

  this.api = Object.create(Oanda);
  this.api.init(config);
}
```

**models.ts**

```
export interface OHLC {
  o: string; // "1.34288"
  h: string; //"1.34336"
  l: string; //1.34278"
  c: string; //1.34315"
}

export interface Candle {
  complete: boolean; //true
  volume: number; //283
  time: string; //2020-02-28T17:50:00.000000000Z
  mid: OHLC;
}

//{"instrument":"USD_CAD","granularity":"M5",
//"candles":[
//{"complete":true,"volume":90,"time":"2020-02-28T21:55:00.000000000Z",
//"mid":{"o":"1.33974","h":"1.33974","l":"1.33932","c":"1.33968"}}]}
export interface CandleRes {
  instrument: string; //ex: "USD_CAD"
  granularity: string; //ex "M5"
  candles: Candle[];
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error message and is it "models" or "Models"?

Comment: @adlopez15 thanks fixed my typo. all class names are completely lowercase. I added the error message - even though it doesnt seem to make sense

Comment: Where is CandleRes declared?

Comment: `api.getCandles(...` instead of `this.api.getCandles(...`?

Comment: If it crashes on this variable declaration `let candles: CandleRes` then we need to see the typescript error message. We don't see it yet.

Comment: @Andreas_D how would I show you the TS error message? The only error message I have is in the electron browser window console tab (When I open developer tools). There is no error in the terminal when I run `npm start` to launch the app

Comment: I only see you initialize the `api`  variable, without assigning anything to it. It can be the reason for the error. If it is not, please extend the example showing the assignment.

Comment: @vicpermir I tried that, but `api` is global (declared at the top of the file, initialized after window loaded)

Comment: @SergiiVorobei Added the setupApi method

Answer (score 1):

You `api` variable is declared in the global scope, and you are trying to access it inside of functions using `this.api` which is incorrect. Just look at how the electron example uses `mainWindow` in your `main.ts`.

You do this once in `getDataAsync()` and twice in `setupApi()`. Change all your `this.api` to just `api` and this particular problem should be gone.

If you want to expand knowledge in this area, here is an excellent article: ['this' in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt seem to solve my problem (I get the same error). I also tried to call setupApi() immediately after it was initialized (at the top of the file) and it apparently never runs..... perhaps this could be the issue? the api var is never initialized? (weird that it works before however)

Comment: Very weird indeed, because I just tried it myself with all your code and this little change and the error goes away.

Comment: I think I understand now... When I moved my code from the preload.ts (which required node) to the renderer.ts I ran into the issue you described

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Glad I could help you in some way :)